# security service is not available

Tags: coldfusion

I've installed ColdFusion 11 in my workstation, connnected CF with IIS webserver. Also upgraded CF11 to its 13th update. It was ran fine on the day I've installed ColdFusion. But from the next day, when I launch ColdFusion administrator or, any cfm pages from the webroot directory, it is giving the following error.

> HTTP Error 500.0 - The Security service is not available.

While checking coldfusion logs, I found the following message,

> coldfusion.server.ServiceFactory$ServiceNotAvailableException: The
>   Security service is not available.

It happened twice, last time also same problem, but I've uninstalled and reinstalled, now again same problem.

So how can we fix the above error and make the CF to work?

Comment: Can you try to re-establish iis site connectors from `Drive:\ColdFusion11\cfusion\runtime\bin\wsconfig.exe`

Comment: yeah that I did already, but same issue persist..